# Fluent configuration of relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my model I have some entities which refer to an instance of Image class

```
    public class Image
  {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string URL { get; set; }

  }

public abstract class TeamBase
  {

    public Image Image { get; set; }

  }

public class NewsArticle
{      
  public Image Image { get; set; }

}
```

[image]

What I would to do is implement delete cascade of Images by delete of NewsArticles and other entities

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
  NewsArticle newsArticle = _repository.Get((int)id);
  _repository.Delete(newsArticle);
  _repository.Save();      
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

So in the override of OnModelCreating what is the right option of declaring the relationship of every entity which refer an Image instance? Is the following approach the right choice?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<NewsArticle>()
                    .HasOptional(n => n.Image)
                    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>()
                    .HasOptional(n => n.Image)
                    .WithOptionalPrincipal()
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
```

Comment: what is the relationship between image, newsarticle and staff? one image can be used by many newsarticles and can also be used by many staff?

Comment: @YuliamChandra its a 1:0/1 relation, but yes, may entities can refer the same image

Comment: if many entities can refer to the same image, it's one to many, one image can be referred by many newsarticlers, and one image can also be referred by many staff, you want a behavior where deleting a newsarticle (dependent) will also delete the image (principal) ?

Comment: yes image can have a one to many relation versus newsarticle or staff, of player etc, but I don't want put a navigation property NewsArticleID and a StaffID and a PlayerID to Image, and yes I'd like the behaviour you say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think want you need is replacing `WithOptionalPrincipal()` with `WithMany()` as long as `Image` entity doesn't have collection of `NewsArticles`.

Config

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NewsArticle>()
            .HasOptional(n => n.Image)
            .WithMany()  // no collection property on Image
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Staff>()
            .HasOptional(n => n.Image)
            .WithMany() // no collection property on Image
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

If `Image` has `NewsArticles` and `Staffs` collection property, the `WithMany()` should mention it, `WithMany(x => x.NewsArticles)` and `WithMany(x => x.Staffs)`.

```
public class Image
{
    public ICollection<NewsArticle> NewsArticles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Staff> Staffs { get; set; }
}
```

The `NewsArticle` table in database will have generated `Image_ID` column in the database since you are using independent association (there is no `ImageID` property on NewsArticle).

The `Image` table in the database will not have any additional column.

Deleting an `Image` will also delete any `NewsArticle` or `Staff` that refers to current deleted image.